# Failed to demangle superclass with Cocoapods in Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

After moving to Xcode 10.2, when running my app I get a crash with the error `failed to demangle superclass of MyClass from mangled name MySuperClass`.

The crash occurs when I try to create an instance of MyClass. I am using CocoaPods 1.6.1 and have not yet upgraded to Swift 5. The class in question is defined inside a Pod, and is a subclass of a class defined a different Pod (listed as a sub dependency of the first Pod).

Adding to the complexity (unsure if it is related) is that the super class takes a generic, and the sub class defines a concrete type and does not take a generic. I.e.

```
// Inside Pod B:
open class MySuperClass<DataType: Decodable> { ... }

// Inside Pod A:
open class MySubClass: MySuperClass<AConcreteStructConformingToCodable> { ... }

// Inside my project:
let myClass = MySubClass()
```

I have tried overriding the Pod build settings to build with and without optmisation without any change in behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have discovered this in the [Xcode 10.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2), under "Swift Compiler" -> "Known Issues":

> Linking against a static Swift library might create a binary with
>   missing type metadata because the object files that define the
>   metadata inside the static archive are mistakenly considered unused.
>   (47598583)
>
> This can manifest as a Swift runtime error with a message such as:
>   “failed to demangle superclass of MyClass from mangled name ‘’”.
>
> Workaround: If you can rebuild the static library, try building it
>   with whole module optimization enabled. Otherwise, add -all_load to
>   the linker flags in the client binary to ensure all object files are
>   linked into it.

And I was able to resolve the issue by adding `-all_load` to Other Linker Flags of the main *Project*:

[image: -all_load linker flag]

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Just a heads-up for others, that -all_load did not fix the issue for me. And I already had whole module optimisation on for the static library in question.

Comment: doesn't work for me either. @Luke did you have any luck with some other approach?

Comment: Just incase it wasn't clear in my answer, this flag needs to be added to the App project, not the Pods project. That was a mistake I originally made. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JoGoFo If I add it to the App project, I am unable to compile app at all. Get dozens of compile errors: "Undefined symbol: method descriptor for..."

Comment: Not working for me as well :/, anyone found another solution? Tried adding this flag to the project level, pod level, nothing works.

Comment: Anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had commented use_frameworks! in my pod file. Removing the comment and cleaning & building the project again helped me out to get rid of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue. My problem was using static frameworks within the Cocoapods, but creating a dynamic framework while splitting the app in Xcode. Just making my own framework static too resolved the issue.