# Testing rx throws error on scheduler init

Tags: ios, swift

Unit test terminates if I write `var scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)`

my imports

```
import XCTest
import RxTest
```

with error message

> failed to demangle superclass of TestScheduler from mangled name '7RxSwift20VirtualTimeSchedulerCy0A4Test0fecD9ConverterVG'

pod versions

```
pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 5'
pod 'RxTest', '~> 5'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of the Cocoapods + XCode 10.2 platform.

Statement from XCode 10.2 RC notes about known issues:

```
Linking against a static Swift library might create a binary with missing 
type metadata because the object files that define the metadata inside the 
static archive are mistakenly considered unused. (47598583)

This can manifest as a Swift runtime error with a message such as:
“failed to demangle superclass of MyClass from mangled name ‘<mangled name>’”.

Workaround: If you can rebuild the static library, try building it with whole module 
optimization enabled. 
Otherwise, add -all_load to the linker flags in the client binary to 
ensure all object files are linked into it.
```

This [thread](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1907) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584094/failed-to-demangle-superclass-with-cocoapods-in-xcode-10-2) should help you get rid of it.